# Get random object from Object.freeze

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I write `getRandomCounty()` function to return always a random object from `countyCode`:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  countyCode: { [key: string]: string } = Object.freeze({
    '01': 'Alba',
    '02': 'Arad',
    '03': 'Arges',
    '04': 'Bacau',
    '05': 'Bihor',
    '06': 'Bistrita-Nasaud',
    '07': 'Botosani',
    '08': 'Brasov',
    '09': 'Braila',
    10: 'Buzau',
    11: 'Caras-Severin',
    12: 'Cluj',
    13: 'Constanta',
    14: 'Covasna',
    15: 'Dambovita',
    16: 'Dolj',
    17: 'Galati',
    18: 'Gorj',
    19: 'Harghita',
    20: 'Hunedoara',
    21: 'Ialomita',
    22: 'Iasi',
    23: 'Ilfov',
    24: 'Maramures',
    25: 'Mehedinti',
    26: 'Mures',
    27: 'Neamt',
    28: 'Olt',
    29: 'Prahova',
    30: 'Satu Mare',
    31: 'Salaj',
    32: 'Sibiu',
    33: 'Suceava',
    34: 'Teleorman',
    35: 'Timis',
    36: 'Tulcea',
    37: 'Vaslui',
    38: 'Valcea',
    39: 'Vrancea',
    40: 'Bucuresti',
    41: 'Bucuresti S.1',
    42: 'Bucuresti S.2',
    43: 'Bucuresti S.3',
    44: 'Bucuresti S.4',
    45: 'Bucuresti S.5',
    46: 'Bucuresti S.6',
    51: 'Calarasi',
    52: 'Giurgiu'
  });

  getRandomCounty() { // this must return random object from countyCode like {'03': 'Arges'}
     // ?????
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this work for you

```js
countyCode =  [
{'01': 'Alba'},
{'02': 'Arad'},
{'03': 'Arges'},
{'04': 'Bacau'},
{'05': 'Bihor'},
{'06': 'Bistrita-Nasaud'},
{'07': 'Botosani'},
{'08': 'Brasov'},
{'09': 'Braila'},
{'10': 'Buzau'},
{'11': 'Caras-Severin'},
{'12': 'Cluj'},
{'13': 'Constanta'},
{'14': 'Covasna'},
{'15': 'Dambovita'},
{'16': 'Dolj'},
{'17': 'Galati'},
{'18': 'Gorj'},
{'19': 'Harghita'},
{'20': 'Hunedoara'},
{'21': 'Ialomita'},
{'22': 'Iasi'},
{'23': 'Ilfov'},
{'24': 'Maramures'},
{'25': 'Mehedinti'},
{'26': 'Mures'},
{'27': 'Neamt'},
{'28': 'Olt'},
{'29': 'Prahova'},
{'30': 'Satu Mare'},
{'31': 'Salaj'},
{'32': 'Sibiu'},
{'33': 'Suceava'},
{'34': 'Teleorman'},
{'35': 'Timis'},
{'36': 'Tulcea'},
{'37': 'Vaslui'},
{'38': 'Valcea'},
{'39': 'Vrancea'},
{'40': 'Bucuresti'},
{'41': 'Bucuresti S.1'},
{'42': 'Bucuresti S.2'},
{'43': 'Bucuresti S.3'},
{'44': 'Bucuresti S.4'},
{'45': 'Bucuresti S.5'},
{'46': 'Bucuresti S.6'},
{'51': 'Calarasi'},
{'52': 'Giurgiu'} ];

Object.freeze(countyCode);

console.log(getRandomCounty());

function getRandomCounty() 
{ // this must return random object from countyCode like {'03': 'Arges'}
 let keys = Object.keys(countyCode)
return countyCode[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:-

```
function getRandomCounty(obj) {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const randomeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (keys.length));
    return obj[keys[randomeIndex]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class AppComponent {
  countyCode = Object.freeze({
    '01': 'Alba',
    '02': 'Arad',
    '03': 'Arges',
    '04': 'Bacau',
    '05': 'Bihor',
    '06': 'Bistrita-Nasaud',
    '07': 'Botosani',
    '08': 'Brasov',
    '09': 'Braila',
    10: 'Buzau',
    11: 'Caras-Severin',
    12: 'Cluj',
    13: 'Constanta',
    14: 'Covasna',
    15: 'Dambovita',
    16: 'Dolj',
    17: 'Galati',
    18: 'Gorj',
    19: 'Harghita',
    20: 'Hunedoara',
    21: 'Ialomita',
    22: 'Iasi',
    23: 'Ilfov',
    24: 'Maramures',
    25: 'Mehedinti',
    26: 'Mures',
    27: 'Neamt',
    28: 'Olt',
    29: 'Prahova',
    30: 'Satu Mare',
    31: 'Salaj',
    32: 'Sibiu',
    33: 'Suceava',
    34: 'Teleorman',
    35: 'Timis',
    36: 'Tulcea',
    37: 'Vaslui',
    38: 'Valcea',
    39: 'Vrancea',
    40: 'Bucuresti',
    41: 'Bucuresti S.1',
    42: 'Bucuresti S.2',
    43: 'Bucuresti S.3',
    44: 'Bucuresti S.4',
    45: 'Bucuresti S.5',
    46: 'Bucuresti S.6',
    51: 'Calarasi',
    52: 'Giurgiu'
  });

  getRandomCounty() { // this must return random object from countyCode like {'03': 'Arges'}
     const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.countyCode);
     return this.countyCode[props[Math.floor(Math.random() * props.length)]];
  }
}

const appComponent = new AppComponent();

console.log(appComponent.getRandomCounty());
```